# Magento ftp access

Tags: magento-1.9, development, ftp

I have a magento website with hotel booking extension installed , now i am hiring a developer for frontend theme who will work from remote , if i give him only the FTP Access to site , can he download whole site on his laptop/pc..actually i dont want any body to use my software , he should only develop the theme and finish, is there any way by which i can restrict him from downloading anything to his local pc/computer please help/suggest

Comment: is there any specific extension or files you need to protect?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. A theme can be developed on a standalone installation. Someone doesn't need FTP access for that. If you have specific extensions installed you can provide those to your developer so he can replicate your envoirement.
2. Although it is not a very good idea to develop on your live/main envoirement, you can restrict access to specific folders for the FTP account you provide to the developer. You should be able to do that from your hosting control panel. Or ask your hosting provider for support.
3. This one might seem like a strange suggestion, but is a very good idea in the long run. Work with professionals who you can trust :)